# Pandas multiple boolean drops

Tags: python, pandas

I've been trying to do multiple drops in pandas DF line by line like so:

```
df_clean = df_merged[df_merged.GDP_current != '..']
df_clean = df_clean[df_clean.GDP_growth != '..']
```

Is there a more efficient way of doing this in one line? I tried with the codes below but it does not work:

```
df_clean = df_merged['GDP_current' != '..'] | df_merged['GDP_growth' != '..'] | df_merged['GDP_per_capita' != '..']
```

OR

```
df_clean = df_merged.drop[df_merged['GDP_growth' == '..'] | df_merged['GDP_current' == '..'] | df_merged['GDP_per_capita' == '..']]
```

Comment: Are you wanting logical `or` or `and` here? so do you want only rows where any of the columns of interest do not contain '..' or rows where all 3 do not contain '..'?

Answer (score 0):

IIUC then you need to wrap your conditions in parentheses due to operator precedence:

```
df_clean = df_merged[(df_merged['GDP_current' != '..']) | (df_merged['GDP_growth' != '..']) | (df_merged['GDP_per_capita' != '..'])]
```

Comment: Tried but it came out as an error:
df_clean2 = df_merged[(df_merged['GDP_growth' != '..']) | (df_merged['GDP_current' != '..']) | (df_merged['GDP_per_capita' != '..'])]

pandas/index.pyx in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas/index.c:3824)()

pandas/index.pyx in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas/index.c:3704)()

pandas/hashtable.pyx in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas/hashtable.c:12280)()

pandas/hashtable.pyx in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas/hashtable.c:12231)()

KeyError: True

Comment: You'll need to post raw input data, code to create your df and the code that produces this error